# localhost IP address without network

Tags: ip, localhost

I noticed that when querying `ipconfig` in cmd, I get the IP address only if I am connected to the Internet or another network, but nothing comes out when I am disconnected. In this case, what is the address used for localhost, say when debugging an ASP.NET project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The localhost address is 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) or ::1 (IPv6)
This is the internal IP address for your computer, even if you are connected to a network.

Comment: Thanks, man. You helped me, and thanks for the ipv6 info.